# why this error happens when I use dynamic_cast?

Tags: c++, dynamic-cast

I want to downcast a object but it causes 'cannot dynamic_cast' error..
(source is not of class type)

what is the problem??

this is my code,

```
class A{...}

class B: public A{...}


A& x;
dynamic_cast<B&>(&x))!=0 //error here (source is not of class type)
```

Comment: Show us a [mcve] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Btw; `x` is a *reference*. Not a class instance.

Comment: In addition to the pointer/reference issue that has been pointed out elsewhere, the class definitions here are, obviously, not legal. This may hide other problems. In particular, if `A` has no virtual functions, the `dyanamic_cast` is not valid. And, of course, `x` has not been initialized, so, again, the code can't compile. In short: too much summarization. Post the smallest code you can come up with that compiles and **shows the problem**.

Answer (score 2):

It is only possible to `dynamic_cast` a class type to a reference.

> what is the problem??

As the error said, the result of `&x` expression is not a class type. It is a pointer type. You've attempted to `dynamic_cast` a pointer to a reference. That is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

You have a mismatch in types between reference and pointer, so the code shouldn't compile. Since you're checking for a null pointer, you apparently want to deal with pointers, so the code should be something on this general order:

```
class A{...}

class B: public A{...}


A& x;
if (dynamic_cast<B *>(&x))!=0)
    // cast was successful
else
    // cast wasn't successful
```

You could also use references throughout, but if you do then an unsuccessful cast is signaled by throwing a `std::bad_cast` exception:

```
void f(A &a) { 
    try {
        B &b = dynamic_cast<B &>(a);
        b.do_something_specific_to_b();
    }
    catch (std::bad_cast const &b) {
        // `a` wasn't of type `B`
    }
}
```

Note, however, that `dynamic_cast` is primarily useful in cases like this, where you're receiving the pointer/reference as a parameter, or for things like a collection of pointers, some of which may point to various different types:

```
std::vector<A *> objects;

for (auto const *a : objects) {
    B *b = dynamic_cast<B *>(a);
    if (b != nullptr)
        b->do_B_specific_stuff();
    else
        a->do_generic_A_stuff();
}
```

Finally, I'd note that if you find yourself using `dynamic_cast` very often, chances are pretty good that you're doing something wrong. I've used C++ since before `dynamic_cast` existed, and in the time it has existed, the number of times I've had to use it could probably be counted on the fingers of one hand (with a couple left over). There are times and places where it's useful (and a few where it's really important), but they really are fairly unusual.